# Looking to texture things like odometers and general analog meters

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm looking to texture something like this..Can I find these online or do I have to custom make them?

[image]

Comment: It's not really a question about Blender  ;)  you can easily recreate this with a vector editor like Inkscape or Illustrator

Comment: Agree with moonboots, 10min job in any vector application.

Comment: On top of that, you can easily find variations through [google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=analog+meter+face&rlz=1C1GGRV_enCZ763CZ763&sxsrf=ALeKk02-6t0VkwwkDc4JQcRc0tWVxd6MDg:1594562412941&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC3sfx78fqAhVF4aQKHeNyCesQ_AUoAXoECA4QAw&biw=1920&bih=898)